# Walk a mixed variable from the inside out PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I have the following Object/Array structure in PHP:

```
Object
(
    id => *random number 10000-99999*
    name =>
    parent => *reference to the parent Object* // null, so this is the root element
    child => Array
        (
            [0] => Object
                (
                    id => *random number 10000-99999*
                    name => row
                    parent => *reference to the parent Object* // points to root element
                    child => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Object
                                (
                                    id => *random number 10000-99999*
                                    name => column
                                    parent => *reference to the parent Object* //row
                                    child => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Object
                                                (
                                                    id => *random number 10000-99999*
                                                    name => link
                                                    parent => *reference to the parent Object* // column
                                                    child => Array ()
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [1] => Object
                                (
                                    id => *random number 10000-99999*
                                    name => column2
                                    parent => *reference to the parent Object* //row
                                    child => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Object
                                                (
                                                    id = *random number 10000-99999*
                                                    name = article
                                                    parent => *reference to the parent Object* // column2
                                                    child => Array ()
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                            [2] => Object
                                (
                                    id = *random number 10000-99999*
                                    name = column3
                                    parent => *reference to the parent Object* //row
                                    child => Array ()
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Object
                (
                    id = *random number 10000-99999*
                    name = link2
                    parent => *reference to the parent Object* // points to root element
                    child => Array ()
                )
        )
)
```

I want to process this variable from the deepest Object. In to out. Like this:

1. link
2. column
3. article
4. column2
5. column3
6. row
7. link

Does anyone has a good solution for this? I can write the suitable algorith for this. I just want to know does anybody has a proven solution.

Comment: A Recursive algorithm will be your friend here.. at least the simplest implementation anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever solution, you probably need to iterate into the array to find the deepest "name" and then iterate back. You can minimize overhead by storing the first iteration and reverse it automatically upon finding the deepest.

Sorry lunch is looming, so no time to provide a working example ;)

Comment: Not a problem, I'm just hoping that someone faces the same problem.